How should you test classes that access localized properties?
Suppose you have a class that accesses a property (perhaps, it's a GUI class)
How do you test it in Java?

You can inject (and mock) a ResourceBundle

import javax.swing.JLabel;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

// simplistic example
public class GreetingPanel extends JPanel {
    private ResourceBundle bundle;

    public GreetingPanel(ResourceBundle bundle) {
        this.bundle = bundle;
        add(new JLabel(bundle.getString("greeting)));
    }
}

Pro: Exposing and mocking dependencies is a "golden standard" in unit testing
Con: One more dependency in your constructor. If you already have a lot of them, it may be a concern

You can set up test properties. Probably, you'll just copy an existing list to avoid extra work

Pro: You don't need to add another argument in your constructor
Con: You'll probably have to manually synchronize the two property lists in case keys are removed/added. It may make your tests fragile. Even if you don't care about values (you test logic), you'll have to keep the property list up-to-date so that your tests don't fail due to missing keys

(I believe it's the best way) Write and use DefaultableResourceBundle instead

import javax.swing.JLabel;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

// simplistic example
public class GreetingPanel extends JPanel {
    private ResourceBundle bundle;

    public GreetingPanel() {
        ResourceBundle wrappedBundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("application");
        this.bundle = DefaultableResourceBundle.of(wrappedBundle, key -> key);
        add(new JLabel(bundle.getString("greeting)));
    }
}

// something like this
public class DefaultableResourceBundle extends ResourceBundle {
    private final ResourceBundle delegate;
    private final UnaryOperator<String> defaultFunction;

    private DefaultableResourceBundle(ResourceBundle delegate, UnaryOperator<String> defaultFunction) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
        this.defaultFunction= defaultFunction;
    }

    public static DefaultableResourceBundle of(ResourceBundle delegate, UnaryOperator<String> defaultFunction) {
        return new DefaultableResourceBundle(delegate, defaultFunction);
    }

    @Override
    public String getString(String key) {
        // try to get it from the delegate, else apply
        // defaultFunction on the key and return the result
    }

    // override getObject(), getStringArray() in a similar way

    // override the abstract getKeys() to perform a simple delegation
}

Pro: You don't have to maintain a list of test properties, nor add another dependency to your tested classes
Con: You'll have to write a bit of code
What do you think?

What do you mean by test properties?

@Kissaki properties used for tests. In Maven project, the property file would sit in the test directory

@DocBrown I replaced the example with another one

@SergeyZolotarev: I am not a Java guy, and your question IMHO expects a little bit too much from readers knowing what a ResourceBundle is, what ResourceBundle.getBundle does and what you mean by "test properties" ( I guess you mean by-value pairs for initializing a ResourceBundle. instance, right?). I had to lookup  all these things, but I guess finally cut myself through this jungle. Maybe next time , you try to write your question having in mind not everyone here is a Java dev here.

@DocBrown but why does Software Engineering have a java tag if it's not ok to ask Java-specific questions?

@SergeyZolotarev: it is perfectly fine to ask Java specific questions, but here are several readers like me who can read and understand Java (and sometimes answer related questions) as long as askers don't assume we all know exactly how certain library functions work in specific contexts.  You might think of your Java examples as "pseudo code" for explaining your software engineering issue.

I guess your DefaultableResourceBundle idea is a step into the right direction, though I guess currently is a little bit overengineered and may be implemented in a simpler manner. Moreover, I think you are mixing up the issue of not extending the constructor parameters with the issue of keeping your tests stable, these are two different things and should be approached separately.
Normally, I would say all you need for a stable test is one stable ResourceBundle instance, independent from any local application settings, and I guess your application has one or more default resource bundle files (or lists) which you can use and reuse in tests. Hence I am not convinced there is an urgent need for mocking this object. Of course, when you think there is no such default file available which is stable enough, you may derive a ResourceBundleMock from the abstract class ResourceBundle and provide methods which just return their input as output.
Then there is this second issue: you want to avoid the extra constructor parameter in your UI elements
  GreetingPanel(ResourceBundle bundle)

which can indeed become somewhat annoying when you have several of such classes and objects to initialize.
Your idea to solve this is
   ResourceBundle.getBundle("application");

directly inside GreetingPanel to get the bundle, which is nothing but the well-known Service Locator pattern. If I got this right, your code relies on this method returning null when run inside a test, and provide an instance of a class which can either behave as a ResourceBundle or as a mock for the former, depending on how it is initialized. For my taste, there is too much "overly clever" code necessary in each UI element with this solution (and a class where instances sometimes behave as a mock, sometimes as real resource bundle - seriously?).
My alternative suggestion would be to implement a very simple service locator, like a class MyResourceBundleProvider with a public method getBundle, which encapsulates the determination of the right resource bundle, something along the lines of
public class MyResourceBundleProvider
{
     public static ResourceBundle getBundle()
     {
          // when in testing context, return a stable default bundle,
          //   or a ResourceBundleMock instance
          //
          // when in application context, return ResourceBundle.getBundle("application");
          // ...
     }
}

Now, the constructor of the GreetingPanel will look like this
public GreetingPanel() {
    this.bundle = MyResourceBundleProvider.getBundle();
    add(new JLabel(bundle.getString("greeting)));
}

which is IMHO simpler to understand and to maintain.

Thank you. Though whenever your class has a static dependency, you can't really unit test it (if the static dependency acts up, the test will fail for the wrong reason)

If throwing builders are ok, it may be an option to consider. On the other hand, mixing optional and required builder setters may cause annoyance for the developer (they'll have to check beforehand which setters are mandatory to call to avoid pesky exceptions in the build())

@SergeyZolotarev: I have no idea what you are talking of. Is anything you wrote related to my answer?

Absolutely. You have a static dependency on a service locator class (which makes true unit testing impossible)

If it's ok for builders to throw (it has its drawbacks, as I pointed out), the constructor may have one dependency instead (on the builder). Then, it may have setters that set required dependencies (whether it's a resource bundle or a service locator)

@SergeyZolotarev: that static dependency is not worse for unit testing than the static dependency on "ResourceBundle.getBundle". It just encapsulates the switch between application context and test context in a central place.

First, it is a good idea if most of your code doesn’t need to access any bundles at all, but just calls a method that returns a suitable string for some purpose. Why is this a good idea? Well, because first your boss told you “this doesn’t need localising, don’t use any resource bundles”, and six months later the exact same boss tells you “we need this localised into French, why don’t you have resource bundles”, and then it turns out some messages come from a server, and this and that, and all the time your code stays unchanged.
So you have one class responsible for everything. You inject whatever resource bundle you want into that class. So your same testing code can be adapted to check any localised resources.
I wouldn’t use a default bundle. Several methods: 1. You use an English bundle. 2. You use a bundle created by the developers, assuming they create a rough version, while someone else polishes it up to become the English version shown to customers. 3 Like Microsoft does, you create a language that is English with áççẽñťš everywhere, which shows quickly that everything is localised and nothing was forgotten.

Thank you. Does it mean you prefer ResourceBundles declared in the constructor?

It’s probably the best place, so you know it’s not forgotten. It doesn’t make much difference because usually you create this object only once. (There have been questions about what to do if the user can switch the language at runtime. It’s tricky because this is an incredibly pervasive global variable or state, and changing it without bad side effects can be difficult).
